# Is it possible for human being to re-design checkout in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am creating magento2 online store for our client, I got the design, everything went okay with some small bumps. But when I got to checkout. I really wish I never born on this planet.

I cannot find any tutorial other than how to add field to default luna theme in checkout or a static plain text message above the shipping form.

What I need to achieve is a one-step checkout that looks like this

[image]

First part is the billing form, second is the password form for account creation, third one is the shipping form if it differs from the billing. Then on the sidebar is summary of items in cart, grand total, and payment method (and now as i am writing i have noticed that there is no shipping method selection...)

on the bottom of the page is checkbox for accepting terms and conditions and a button to finish the order.

In Magento 1 this would be not easy but not hard to do also. I have no clue how to even start. All tuts I have found considers only adding some field, or moving the billing above the shipping, etc. One step checkout is even not mentioned anywhere.

Can someone provide any good resource? Magento devdocs was not enough for me to understand how that works. MAgeplaza and other blogs does not mention things i need.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's possible to redeign checkout in magento2.

There are **two ways** to do that

1)  Use third party module. Below are some free modules for example.

[link 1](https://github.com/magento-2/one-step-checkout)

[link 2](https://marketplace.magento.com/iwd-opc.html)

You can use modules like this.

2) Second way is customize default magento2 module

> module-checkout

[Click here for more info](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html)

Thanks !!

Comment: Thank you, i will check out how IWD done the job, since mageplaza (link 1) is no longer available on gihub for free download.